# How to collect a list of folders in ansible without errors?

Tags: ansible

You have a list for folders that you want to copy from the remote machine to the local one and *not all of them may exist*.

Current approach does generate noisy falseerrors on the logs when somefolder are not found:

```
- set_fact:
    folders:
      - /foo
      - /bar

- synchronize:
    dest: "{{ log_path }}"
    mode: pull
    src: "{{ item }}"
    verify_host: true
  ignore_errors: true
  with_items: "{{ folders }}"
```

What I want to achieve is a behavior where rsync runs without any errors when some of the folders are missing.

Current ansible behavior produces some noise like:

```
rsync: change_dir "foo" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1650) [Receiver=3.1.2]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

I obviously considered using stat module to verify if the folders do exist but the problem is that I cannot use loops with blocks.

Does anyone knows another clean way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see where the problem is with using `stat`. Here is a test playbook I ran on my machine that reflects what I understood you are trying to do.

```
---
- name: Test selective log synchro
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true

  vars:
    remote_log_path: /var/log
    local_copy_path: /tmp
    folder_names:
      - containers
      - cups
      - IDoNotExist

  tasks:
    - name: Check which folders exist on remote
      stat:
        path: "{{ remote_log_path }}/{{ item }}"
      register: log_folders_check
      loop: "{{ folder_names }}"

    - name: Debug registered var to see structure on -v
      debug:
        var: log_folders_check
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Create a list of existing folders only
      set_fact:
        existing_log_folders: "{{ log_folders_check.results | json_query('[?(stat.exists)][item][]') }}"

    - name: Debug calculated list on -v
      debug:
        var: existing_log_folders
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Make sure local needed folders exist
      file:
        path: "{{ local_copy_path }}/{{ item }}"
        state: directory
        owner: root
        group: root
      loop: "{{ existing_log_folders }}"

    - name: Sync existing folders locally
      synchronize:
        dest: "{{ local_copy_path }}/{{ item }}/"
        src: "{{ remote_log_path }}/{{ item }}/"
        mode: pull
      with_items: "{{ existing_log_folders }}"
```

Which gives (run with `-v` if you want to see the registered/set vars)

```
PLAY [Test selective log synchro] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check which folders exist on remote] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=containers)
ok: [localhost] => (item=cups)
ok: [localhost] => (item=IDoNotExist)

TASK [Debug registered var to see structure on -v] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Create a list of existing folders only] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug calculated list on -v] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Make sure local needed folders exist] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=containers)
ok: [localhost] => (item=cups)

TASK [Sync existing folders locally] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=containers)
ok: [localhost] => (item=cups)

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```